# Why does a very small checkinterval not slow down CPU-intensive multithreading in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, gil

```
from threading import Thread

def countdown(start, end):
    while end > start:
        end -= 1

def multi_thread(n):
    t1 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(0, n // 2))
    t2 = Thread(target=countdown, args=(n // 2, n))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    import sys

    sys.setswitchinterval(1)
    print(timeit.timeit("""import gil;gil.multi_thread(10000000);""", number=1))
    # 1.07s
    sys.setswitchinterval(0.001)
    print(timeit.timeit("""import gil;gil.multi_thread(10000000);""", number=1))
    # 1.09s
```

After reading the [NewGIL.pdf](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/NewGIL.pdf), I think that a small interval will result in more thread sleep/wakeup operations, and then the total execution time should be longer. Am I wrong?

Test environment: quad-core Ubuntu16.04 python3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your total task only takes about 1 second.  So with a switch interval of 0.001 seconds, there will only be about 1/0.001 = a thousand switches *total*.  The cost of each switch (which occurs "at C speed") is more naturally measured in microseconds than in milliseconds, so a thousand of them remain cheap compared to the total 1 second elapsed time.

To see more of an effect, try setting the switch interval to `1e-6`.

In real life, the real cost of thread switching is more often the *associated* costs:  a thread gets enough time to fill HW instruction and data caches, then gets switched out and the new thread suffers cache misses at various levels at first.  Your example doesn't have any of those costs (the code and data each thread uses is relatively tiny, and both threads' stuff fits even in L1 cache simultaneously).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct.
A lower switch interval means that there will be more frequent conditional polls against the GIL to see if it can be acquired.
And because we can't run threads in parallel due to the GIL, more frequent context switches actually harms our performance.

If you want to improve the performance of your system you're going to have to used a [multiprocessed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) solution.